# Create a custom range in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image]

I am trying to make a range selector like this can anyone help

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(0);

const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedValue(e.target.value);
};

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
            onInput={handleChange}
            type="range"
            min="0"
            value={selectedValue}
            max="5"
            step="1"
            list="tick-list"
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have managed the working part of this design, I just want the CSS to be like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see working version below.

First thing to note is that you should use react state to manage the value of the the slider - regardless of how often you want to interact with it.

A nice way to get the steps of ten is divide the current value by 10, round it up to the nearest integer, and multiply it by 10 again. Note that you should not mutate the actual sliderValue variable but should rather use a new variable. This method was used in example 1.

```
const shownValue = Math.round(sliderValue / 10) * 10
```

If you would like to only have the slider jump in large steps (example 2) then you should just set the max attribute on the slider input to 6 and multiply the result by 10.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example1 = () => {
  const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState(0);
  const shownValue = Math.round(sliderValue / 10) * 10
  
     return (
      <div>
        <h3>
        Example 1 - smooth
        </h3>
        <div>
          <input
            type="range"
            name="range"
            id="range"
            min="0"
            max="60"
            value={sliderValue}
            onChange={e => {
            setSliderValue(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          {shownValue}
        </div>
      </div>
   );
};

const Example2 = () => {
  const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState(0);
  
     return (
      <div>
        <h3>
        Example 2 - incremental
        </h3>
        <div>
          <input
            type="range"
            name="range"
            id="range"
            min="0"
            max="6"
            value={sliderValue}
            onChange={e => {
            setSliderValue(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          {sliderValue * 10}
        </div>
      </div>
   );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Example1 />
    <Example2 />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: i have it working alreay i am looking for the design like that in the image